# How can I click (bypass) a submit button using Python Selenium, when the button gets disabled after using .clear() or .send_keys()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

As the title says, how can I `.click()` a `button` using `Selenium`, when the button gets "`disabled`" after using the method `clear` or `send_keys`?

---

**Before:**

[image]

---

That's the page status when I open it's `url`... but then right after I run my code to find the `textbox` and `replace` it's value, the element gets `disabled` (maybe by some sort of `JS`) right after I `clear` it's content or write something to it using `send_keys`.

---

**After:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
txt_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="txtValor4"]')
txt_value.clear() #this disables the button
txt_value.send_keys(str(123,45)) #this also disables the button
```

**My question is:**

> How can I bypass this website protection and press the `Continuar` button?

I thought about disabling `JS`, but the whole website relies on it to produces the requires documents.. wrong alternative.

So I thought about using the button properties to simulate the pressing of the button... just don't know if it's possible, or how I could do this.

Another option was blocking only the `JS` that disables the button maybe mapping where the command comes from using the `inspect element` and `network tools`...

So is there any way to achieve this?

*ps.: I can't give the URL because it requires my login data.*

Comment: Sounds like it's getting disabled due to a form validation, as in it doesn't like what you're entering as the value into the text field. It could be that the text field isn't registering a change. You could try clicking outside of the text area after send_keys in order to have it 'take' the change

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the problem! I took the picture right after the `clear()` and `send_keys()` methods. I could locate the element, clear its values and insert the correct ones. The `clear()` and `send_keys()` methods are the root of my problem. Something triggers the "disable button" protection method of the site when I run them... But if I use `b.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)` it works! I can clear the content without disabling the button... But when I use the `send_keys('123,45')` (with values), the button gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could bypass this using `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('txtValor4').‌​value = 123.45")`, to pass the values into the textbox, so the button didn't got `disabled` and I could press the `Continue` button.

Even bypassing this, the result wasn't the expected! The value that I entered was supposed to be corrected by some sort of interest. But bypassing this, the value isn't corrected.

Today the user that asked the program told me that everytime I change the value inside this `textbox`, I must press the `Calculate` button.

So, instead of inefficiently bypassing this `disable` method, I could solve my problem using:

```
b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="txtValor4"]')
b.clear()
b.send_keys('123.45')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="btnCalcular4"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="btnContinuar4"]').click()
```

This way the tax value is corrected by interest and the website generate the `.pdf` with the exact value that I was expecting.

Many thanks for everyone that put some time and effort trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you can't directly do this through normal means. Selenium WebDriver is made to simulate real use of a browser. It may be possible however to use the execute_script function. (Java Selenium has a built in JavascriptExecutor class, I assume this is python's version.) The execute_script function allows Selenium to perform tasks that a human interacting with a browser can't do.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('buttonid').click()")
```

Or something along those lines should work. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: You answer enlightened me! I could bypass this using `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('textboxID').value = 123.45")`, to pass the values into the textbot, so the button didn't got disabled and I could press the continue button. I really appreciate your effort into helping me!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get any solution with selenium and javascript, you can use Sikuli concept. To click that element, take the image of the 'Continuar' button and save it in resources folder.

```
String elementImg=Path of the Image;
    screen.click(elementImg);
```

Comment: I tagged JS because the website is using JS... my code is actually in Python. Anyway, thanks for your help, I've never heard of Sikuli Concept! ;-)